# symfony2 expected array, got integer in setting in password encryption

Tags: php, symfony-2.4

I'm learning Symfony2 and having an issue with security.yml. I'm trying to set bcrypt algorithm to admin user in security.yml with cost 12 but I get an error which says that security.encoders.cost expects an array.

I use the example from the book and [Symfony2 Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password)

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:
                    password: userpass
                    roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                admin:
                    password: $2y$12$3ueSi649.H6ky.9HYgiL/.mPkL3dWb8haWR//RHZHYHx5wbD.XdI.
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
```

Comment: What version of Symfony2 are you using?

Comment: what is your php version. If its 5.4 or lower you have to install "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3" library

Comment: no, it's not that. it's php 5.5.9

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve the problem entirely but i got it to work with the bcrypt algorithm.
The application was throwing 'expected array, got integer in security.encoders.cost'. It was also throwing that error when i removed the cost parameter from security.yml but for the 'algorithm' value that was algorithm: bcrypt.

The soluction was to put...

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: bcrypt
```

what i didn't do in the code of the question. The problem is that the error still arises when i put the cost parameter.